# What is the difference between API & Framework

Tags: java, api, frameworks, jakarta-ee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Framework Vs. API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724380/framework-vs-api)

Hey,

I want to know what are the differences between an `API` & a `Framework`.

Thanks