# When exactly is parenthesis needed when executing a function

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, function-call

I am new to JavaScript and would like to understand something about functions. Why is it that when calling a function to run, one usually has to end of with parenthesis (), and if not it will just display the contents of the function. But when binding an event listener to a element, one may not use parenthesis when calling the function and if they are used it will run as soon as the page loads. (same is true when using the setTimeout or SetInterval function).

Comment: When you're initializing an event listener, or initializing a timeout or interval you're _not_ calling the function. You're passing the function to the framework to be called at a later designated time.

Comment: So when is the function ever called

Comment: As I already said, it's called by the framework, not by you.

Comment: Basically, thats how javascript works. It knows to call it by itself

Comment: @PatrickRoberts JavaScript is not a framework. The invocation of the referenced handler is handled by the DOM element - - it really is not part of JavaScript at all.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The DOM (or whatever place where you register the callback) can be said to be a framework

Comment: @Bergi I think it has to be more specific that that. JQuery, for example, is a library, while Angular is a framework. The DOM is an API,  not a framework.

Comment: APIs and frameworks are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts As a general rule, they are. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724380/framework-vs-api

Comment: _"A framework does introduce the notion of [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)"_ which is exactly what we're talking about here. But enough about semantics, this comment chain is getting ridiculous and the point of my original comment is still valid, even if you disagree with the particular use of terminology.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple once you understand that, in JavaScript, functions are data as well as units of invocable code. That means that you can pass them around, just as if you were passing the number `10` or the string `"test"`.

- When ***invoking*** a function, you must include parenthesis.

  `foo(); // Invokes the foo function`
- When ***referencing*** a function (as data to be used somewhere), you
  don't. Event callbacks are examples of function referencing. In the following example, the string `"click"` and the function `foo` are being passed as arguments (data) to the `.addEventListener()` method of some element. That element, would now have `foo` registered in as a callback function to call if/when that element's `click` event occurs. We don't want to invoke `foo` right now, we just want to let the element know what function to possibly invoke later.

  `element.addEventListener("click", foo); // References foo as the click event callback`

  - Now, things can get a bit more complicated because functions can return a value when they are done running and that value (data) can also be another function. In those cases, we want to invoke a function in order to get the function that it returns back (as data):

```js
function returnAfunction(){
  // When this function is invoked, it will return
  // (as data) another function:
  return function(){
    console.log("You did it!");
  };
}

// Here, notice that the second argument does have parenthesis after it.
// This is because we want the function to run right now and whatever its
// returned value is will then become the actual event callback for the
// button element.
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", returnAfunction());
```

```html
<button type="button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Thanx. i just didnt understand that once you referenced it,  the framework will call it later automatically like Patrick Roberts pointed out

Comment: @JoeStarbright That is what `.addEventListener()` does. It's job is to **add** an event listener (function) to the element so that when the referenced event (`click` in this case) occurs, any registered handlers will automatically be invoked. The idea of function referencing is central to how JavaScript operates.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because when you define a function, you may pass it some parameters like

```
const isUserValid = (username, password) => {
  for (i = 0; i < database.length; i++) {
    if (database[i].username === username && database[i].password === password) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

and so is true for when you want to execute the function. But when you add an event listener, then you are automatically calling the function to execute on (i.e. click)